# CSS/HTML Error, Input box inside Input box?

Tags: html, css, center

What I'm trying to do is make an input field and center it on the page. I have managed to do just that, but it looks like an input box on top of another one and it is not paying attention to the style rules I gave it. Here is what it looks like:

[image: Screen capture]

The black and grey box is supposed to be the input box, obviously.

Here is the HTML:

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
.styles{
   height:30px;
   width:286px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   border-radius: 4px;
   -moz-background-clip: padding;
   -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
   background-clip: padding-box;
   border: 1px solid #5E5E5E;
   padding:0 10px;
   background-color: #000000;
   color:#BFBFBF;
   outline: none;
   input-align: center;
}

.abs-centered {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
</style>
<div class="styles abs-centered">
<body bgcolor="#25383C">
<input name="name" type="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"/>
</div>
```

I haven't put `html` and `body` and stuff in yet because I'm just trying to sort this problem.

Comment: Incase I got you wrong, you wanna have black "box"/div as your input text box?

Comment: Yeah, that black box in the picture should be the text box.

Comment: Your body is inside your div. Supposed to be the other way around

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a separate div for the look of the input box.

Use this:

```
input
{
     //put the styling in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're applying the styles to a `<div>`, not the actual `<input>`.  Think of the `<div>` as a container that has your body and input inside of it.  (As an aside, the `<body>` should contain everything shown on the page, and not be contained in anything beyond the `<html>` tag).

Apply the styles to your `<input>` element, not the `<div>`, and you'll get the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that issue using CSS, like that:

```
input{
   /*My CSS Code*/
}
```

However it's not recommended, since you have also `input type="submit"` which will have a problem because you'll have textbox design on button.

here is more popular and specifc way to edit `input type="text"`

```
input[type="text"]{
    /*My Code*/
}
```

As you can tell, it can be used in `type="password", type="submit"` etc..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your html is a little messed up. the `<html>` and `<head>` tags are mandatory, your first `<div>` tag cannot be before the `<body>` tag and the body tag must be closed. It doesn't change a lot for your problem but when you are trying things in html/css you must be sure to have a code that doesn't have markup error otherwise the layout can end up not being rendered as expected.

As I understand you want your input box to be centered on the page. The css class .abs-centered you have there is telling the the layout engine to center a box relative to his parent.

In your code the div class is being centered relative to the page (`<body>`) box. If you want the input to be black and gray, and centered on the page, you can simple remove the div tag and add both .abs-centered and .styles classes to the input tag.

http://pastebin.com/psHz0psB

If you want to leave the `<div>` box and have the input centered relative to it, you can just add the .abs-centered class to the input. Then you'll have your input centered on the div centered on the page.

I think you should leave the `<div>` because input can be treated as inline elements instead of boxes and some browser may not treat the style as expected. If you just want the input element to be styled remove the .styles class from it so it will be transparent.

hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

You need this: [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eqEPAci/1/edit)

HTML:

```
<body bgcolor="#25383C">
  <div class="styles abs-centered">
    <input id="actual-input" name="name" type="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"/>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.styles{
        height:30px;
    width:286px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-background-clip: padding;
    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #5E5E5E;
    padding:0px 5px;
        background-color: #000000;
        color:#BFBFBF;
        outline: none;
        input-align: center;
}

.abs-centered {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#actual-input{
  height:26px;
  padding:0px;
  width:100%;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:transparent;
  border:0px;
  outline-style:none;
}
```

Screen capture:

[image]